# Child.destroy_all seems to delete the parents also in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I have two associated models i.e:

```
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :children, dependent: :destroy
end
```

and

```
class Child < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :parent
   has_many :toys, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
class Toy < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :child
end
```

And when I try to destroy all Child records, Rails also deletes the parents

```
Child.destroy_all # leads to deleting all child records but ALSO the parent records
```

How can I delete only the children without their parents?

Comment: Actually it should not. `has_many.. dependent: :destroy` you made on `Parent` should remove children of this parent if parent is destroy. There is no link the other way around. You seems to have something else on your code destroying the parent.

Comment: @brcebn Well I've updated the post by including another model that is associated with the `Child`, and so child also `has_many.. dependent: :destroy` too... But I'm not sure if that's the cause?

Comment: Can you create 2 parents and 2 children on each. Then query `Child.destroy_all` and display to output logs? 